What are the reasons Jackal switches to red light in the first season finale?
In the season finale of the Day of the Jackal, when two MI6 agents locate the Jackal's residence in Spain and invade it in late evening, the Jackal switches off all the lights in the residence but turns on red lights in his hidden room, where he stashes his passports, cash, weapons and etc.
I am wondering what the reasons are for him to turn on red lights, not any other colors?

Essentially, it's intended to preserve your night vision in otherwise dark circumstances

While red light isn’t as bright as white light, it does wonders for your night vision. Low-light conditions cause our pupils to dilate. Exposure to bright light causes them to constrict. That means that using an intense light at night can temporarily make it harder to see in the dark once the light turns off. Conversely, red light minimizes pupil dilation, thus preserving night vision.
Source

You'll see this in many movies going back to the WW2 submarine and naval movies where they will switch to red lights at night etc and so red lights are something of a trope.



The actual effectiveness is disputed in more modern times where it's proposed that a dim white light would be better.
See this article

It's also been common for soldiers to put a red filter on torches/flashlights to reduce the light emitted and also preserve night vision when consulting maps, etc.

This however makes it difficult, if not impossible to use the Venetian mirror
